# encoding unicode in dictionary not correct [python]

Tags: python, encoding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s = u'ö'
d = {'s': s}
print d
```

I get {'s': u'\xf6'}, which is not what I want, while I want it to be {'s': u'ö'}.
What should I do...

Comment: Use Python 3 instead.

Comment: I want too.. But this project uses some 3rd party libs without the full python 3 supporting..

Comment: Is this actually a problem? If you print(d['s']) it will print out 'ö'

Comment: @MikeTGW I just tried and it does not

Comment: Here is the output I get in two different terminals:  http://i.imgur.com/UzojT2P.png

Comment: Yes, you are right. But is there any way to print {'s': u'ö'}?

Comment: Could it be that the Terminal you are using is at fault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this horrible piece of code might help:

```
def pretty(mydict):
    string = u'{'
    nkeys = len(mydict.keys())
    for i, key in enumerate(sorted(mydict.keys())):
        item = [key, mydict[key]]
        for j in range(2):
            if type(item[j]) in (str, unicode):
                item[j] = ['', 'u'][type(item[j]) == unicode]+"'"+item[j]+"'"
            else:
                item[j] = str(item[j])
        string += item[0] + ': ' + item[1]
        if i < nkeys-1:
            string += ', '
    string += '}'
    return string

s = u'ö'
d = {'s': s}
print pretty(d)
```

I'm ashamed of myself. But it should output,

```
{'s': 'ö'}
```

I hope it works, I only have Python 3 installed in my laptop and I'm checking this on the repl.it site.
Please note that it's just a rudimentary answer and that it's the software's responsibility to use `u''` every time a unicode string is used. I.e. if you do,

```
d['test'] = 'ê' # instead of u'ê'
```

then d.pretty() will throw an error.
Also note that it will not work on nested objects, i.e. `d[1] = [1, u'ö']` will not display the 'ö' as you wish it to be.

Comment: (and re-edited to add the else clause on lines 9-10)

Comment: (and finally edited to switch from a class to a simple function)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "is not what I want?" `u'ö' == u'\xf6'` Try this:

```
print d['s']
# ö
print ord(d['s'])
# 246
```